# Predefined buttons in CKEditor Mathjax plugin

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, mathjax

CKEditor's Mathjax plugin contains several elements in the dialog: one textarea (id: equation) and one div (id: preview).

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/mathjax/dialogs/mathjax.js

When some mathjax code is entered in the textarea, the formula is written in the div. I am trying to add several predefined buttons that add usual formulae mathjax text to the textarea, so users only have to populate these formulae.

Adding a button into the elements works nice, but I can only access to change the div element. Accessing the textarea does not work, it seems that is not available in any scope at all.

```
id: 'info',
elements: [
    {
        id: 'testButton',
        type: 'button',
        button: 'aaaa',

        onClick: function() {
            // Changing the ID value does work
                preview.setValue('Test');
            // but changing the textarea does not.
                // equation.setValue('Test');
                // document.getElementById('equation').setValue('Test');

        }
    },
    {
        id: 'equation',
        type: 'textarea',
        label: lang.dialogInput,

        onLoad: function() {
            var that = this;

            if ( !( CKEDITOR.env.ie && CKEDITOR.env.version == 8 ) ) {
                this.getInputElement().on( 'keyup', function() {
                    // Add \( and \) for preview.
                    preview.setValue( '\\(' + that.getInputElement().getValue() + '\\)' );
                } );
            }
        },
```

Sorry if this is a simple question, but how can I access to equation textarea?

Answer (score 0):

After much reading, it seems that this is a way, not sure it's the best way though.

```
onClick: function() {
this._.dialog.setValueOf("info","equation","TEST");
}
```